# StoryBoards supporting @2x and -568h file images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, storyboard

In my program I use "StoryBoard" and when I first start the application window should appear with instructions.

So, is it possible to add an image in the UIImageView, in StoryBoard, and run the application on iphone 3gs this image bends

In the application resources are files Introdusing@2x.png, Introdusing-568h@2x.png and Introdusing.png, but on all devices use only Introdusing-568h@2x.png. How to fix it?

Please help....

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand the question.

Comment: I also don't understand the question. Also, an aside spelling issue it's "Introducing" not "Introdusing."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask for an image `image`, iOS will check for `image@2x.png` and `image.png`, using the appropriate one for the device's resolution. iOS will *not* check for `-568h` images, so by providing an image `Introdusing-568h@2x.png`, your program will check for `Introdusing-568h@2x.png` and `Introdusing-568h.png`, and, not finding the latter, it will use `Introdusing-568h@2x.png` in all cases.  You have two options: tell IB to use `Introdusing.png` or `Introdusing@2x.png` and let iOS pick from just those two, or you can determine programmatically whether the device is a retina-4 and use the appropriate image.

Also, PLEASE correct the name; it should be "introducing," not "introdusing," and in context it should probably be a noun, "introduction".

Answer (score 0):

In IB you need to make sure that the image linked to your image view is set to the lowest quality .png file.  So in your case make sure it's set to Introdusing.png and not Introdusing-568h@2x.png.  It will determine the proper image to use at run time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, basically you have 3 files: Introdusing@2x.png, Introdusing-568h@2x.png and Introdusing.png.

If you want ALL devices to use Introdusing-568h@2x.png, then set the UIImage to Introdusing-568h@2x.png file and delete the other two files. Keep in mind this will cause some displaying issues in old iPhone 3G/GS and iPhone 4 screens. You may see distortion as the older iPhones scales the image to fit that screen so test your app for each of the phones and see if that's ok with you.

If you want to use the correct image for the 3GS, iPhone 4/4S and iPhone 5 screens, then set the image to Introdusing.png and UIImageView will figure out which image size is the best one for the different phone models.